# Почему я получаю ошибку при импорте модулей и как ее исправить?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Я хочу сделать сборку на es6 импортах, но застрял на самом первом этапе: самих импортах. Структура папок у меня такая:

```
> start_temlate_2022
     > gulp
          > config
            - path.js
            - ftp.js
            - plugins.js
          > tasks
             - copy.js
          > src
            > files
```

path.js с путями:

```
import * as nodePath from "path";

const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());
const buildFolder = rootFolder;
const srcFolder = "./src";

export const path = {
    build: {
        files: `${buildFolder}` + `/files/`,
    },
    src: {
        files: `${srcFolder}` + `/files/**/*.*`,
    },
    watch: {},

    clean: buildFolder,
    buildFolder: buildFolder,
    srcFolder: srcFolder,
    rootFolder: rootFolder,
    ftp: ``
}
```

Сам gulpfile:

```
import gulp from `gulp`;
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path";

global.app = {
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp
}

import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy";

gulp.task(`default`, copy)
```

Ну и copy.js

```
export const copy = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.files)
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.files))
}
```

При запуске gulp вылетает ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected template string
>
> at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
>
> at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:64:21)

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: У Вас ругается на template string, то есть на строковый литерал. Могу быть не прав, но их нельзя использовать в импорте. Для оператора импорта, требуется обычная строка. К тому же непоянтно зачем Вы их везде пихаете и никоим образом их не используете. В чем смысл вот этого ````${buildFolder}` + `/files/````, если его можно приветси к виду ```${buildFolder}/files/```, для этого и были придуманы шаблонные строки.

Comment: @Simon Да, его можно к этому привести. Изначально так и писал, но подумал, что именно тут и напортачил, поэтому привел к более привычной для себя конкатенации. В имортах вроде бы обчный путь к файлам.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить тот импорт галпа что у Вас есть, на `import gulp from "gulp"`;

Comment: @Simon Да, действительно, поменял все на обычные строки и все заработало. Оформите как ответ, я галочку поставлю, чтоб закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Да на ответ вроде не особо тянет) Рад был помочь)

Comment: @Simon еще как тянет, ошибка-то исправлена. Я вот не знал, что в импортах можно пользоваться только обычными строками. Вдруг еще кто этого не знает, а вопрос уже будет решенный. Не скромничайте, спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас ругается на template string, то есть на строковый литерал. Замените

```
import gulp from `gulp`;
```

на

```
import gulp from "gulp";
```

проблема в том, что для оператора `import`, требуется обычная строка.